# Price movements - last 1 hour change - best way to find value from past 1 hour in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

Example database file (dbfile) with timestamp and value:

```
1516307965 598917802507
1516312165 584337425999
1516324465 584147968883
1516341864 568759422044
1516368865 596288892045`
```

My code:

```
last=``date +%s``

   lasth=$(($last-3600))

   lasthdown=$(($lasth-120))

   lasthup=$(($lasth+120))

   tbh=`sort -u /home/f/dbfile | awk -v lasthdown="$lasthdown" -v lasthup="$lasthup" '$1 > lasthdown && $1 < lasthup' | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'``

   tpr1h=$(bc -l <<< "scale=1;100*($db-$tbh)/$db")`
```

Maybe You know more precission way to match value from last 1 hour...

Comment: What do you think the 2 single ticks on each side of `date +%s` are doing? How come you know to use `$(...)` in the last line of the script but not in the 2nd-last line? Add the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your timestamps are in epoch format, you may want to simply omit the last 2 digits from your `st` variable and search the file, this way you will only have a 99 seconds(1m 39s) precision.
You could use the below 3 lines to achieve that:

```
#get the epoch time stamp from 1 hour ago
st=`date -d '1 hour ago' +%s`
#obtain only the first 8 digits (the 99 second precision)
st1=`echo $st | awk '{print substr($0,1,8);exit}'`
# search the file for the above hour and sort the output to obtain the closest match, then print only the value in the 2nd column for that match
tbh=`grep "${st1}[0-9]\{2\}" ./db.txt| sort -k1 -nu | awk 'END{print $2}'`
echo $tbh
```

Note: You may further decrease precision (or increase if you need that), by changing the below line to omit the last 3 digits of the timestamp, giving you 999 seconds precision.

```
st1=`echo $st | awk '{print substr($0,1,7);exit}'
```